# Show the Common Field Values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I am trying to show the common field data. I can find the field data.

```
 Events.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}).fetch()
    Like:
    abc
    abc
    xyz
```

Now I want to show common data like:

```
abc 
xyz
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: @Neil Lunn Thanks! Your suggested answer is resulted showing from the terminal but my code is for the frontend. How to use distinct in frontend for fetch data?

Comment: No aggregation methods are supported in the minimongo front end engine, not should they be. Asking for "all data" to be returned to a front end and then working out distinct values is a real design anti-pattern. You can implement [meteor methods](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html) which can be called from the client, but execute on the back-end and return their data to the client. That is what you should be doing here.